How would I go about excluding all but certain directories and one filetype in rsync?
For a project on NLP I need a copy of the Project Gutenberg library. Now, the project allows the download of their files, especially if it's for mirroring purposes (I'm planning on setting one up eventually), but for my work I need only a specific subset of the files present.
The directories at the source are organised like so:
|
| - 1 - |
|       |- 1
|       |- 2
|       |...
| - 2
| .
| .
| .
| - 9
| - cache
| - retired
| ...


The only directories I'm interested in are the numbered ones, and the only file type I'm interested in is .txt, I also don't want files ending with -8.txt or -h.txt, but I'm willing to tolerate them for now.
So far I've tried:

--include "*/" --include "*.txt" --exclude "cache" --exclude "images" --exclude "retired" --exclude "pg" --exclude "*-8.txt" --exclude "*" <- this one still pulls in the "cache" folder, since it also contains some .txt files
--include "*/" --include "*.txt" -f'- *\-8.txt' -f'- *\-h.txt' -f'- cache/**' --exclude "cache" --exclude "images" --exclude "retired" --exclude "pg" --exclude "*" <- more or less the same thing

The problem seems to be like this:

I need to exclude everything, since there's an extremely limited set of things I need
I include the numbered directories, since that's all I need
Including *.txt breaks the prior exclusions, because other directories also contain text files.

How would I go about this?

From the post
rsync - exclude all directories except a few,
I quote from the
answer by Darryl E. Clarke:

A simple filter should do the trick. To build on the prior answer with
a proper example -- Explicitly include the parent(s), plus all (**)
sub folders and files. Then exclude everything else. Here's
filter.txt:
+ /include_this_dir/
+ /include_this_dir/**
+ /include_that_dir/
+ /include_that_dir/**
- /** With the command line:

rsync -av --dry-run --filter="merge filter.txt" source_dir/ dest_dir/

Would result in:
sending incremental file list
created directory dest_dir
./
include_that_dir/
include_that_dir/somefile.txt
include_that_dir/subdir/
include_this_dir/

sent 202 bytes  received 65 bytes  534.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)


Add to this your filter of *.txt.
In other words : First include, then exclude all.

this sort of works, but also pulls every file from the numbered directories, including zip and html

You could explicity match the numbered directories with the glob [0-9]/:
 -f'+ [0-9]/' \
 -f'- *-[8h].txt' \
 -f'+ *.txt' \
 -f'- *' \

If the numbers go higher than 9, perhaps also adding -f'+ [0-9][0-9]/ or -f'+ [0-9]*/ would suffice.
